# Where to use nullish operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, logic, operator-keyword, nullish-coalescing

```
function test(val) {
    const hasError = val ?? true;
    if (hasError) {
        //error handling...
    } else {
        //do something...
    }
}
test(null) //error handling...
test(undefined) //error handling...
test('text') //error handling...
test(true) //error handling...
```

like this case i want to filter 'null' and 'undefined'

but it`s work every truthy value.

So i have only one option...

```
const hasError = (val === undefined || val === null);
```

Is there any way of use nullish operator in this case?

and when nullish operator is used generally?

thank you

Comment: `val == null` is also true for `undefined`

Comment: What do you mean by *"but it's work every truthy value"*? `0 ?? true` is `0`, not `true`.

Comment: Looking at your code, I would tend to assume you'd want `= val ?? false`, not `= val ?? true`. (Or `val == null` as @Pointy pointed out.) `= val ?? true` means that if `val` is `null` or `undefined`, `hasError` will get the value `true`, and if `val` is anything else (like `"text"` or `true` or `42`), `hasError` will get that value (`"text"` or `true` or `42`). What values of `val` should mean `hasError` is true?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that

```
const hasError = (val === undefined || val === null);
```

captures the logic you want, then the problem is that

```
const hasError = val ?? true;
```

gives you the *opposite* of that if you're subsequently going to use that flag in an `if` expression.  You'd really want to follow with

```
if (hasError !== true)
```

which is really confusing (to me).  Instead, you can think of the `??` operator giving you the opposite:

```
const noError = val ?? true;
if (!noError)
```

which makes a little more sense. Personally I'd use

```
const hasError = val == null;
```

or just perform the test in the `if` directly.